# Stripe.net in Xamarin.Forms PCL with ASP.NET Core MVC Web API

Tags: xamarin.forms, stripe.net

I am trying to implement Stripe.net into my Xamarin.Forms PCL using an ASP.NET Core MVC Web API. The goal is to process credit card payment from users. My web API runs locally on http://localhost:port for testing purposes.

In the PaymentPage, a user enters their credit card information into Entry objects and when they click the submit Button, a method in the PaymentPageViewModel is called to start the logic:

```
async void OnFinishBookingClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Stripe integration
    var viewModel = (PaymentPageViewModel)this.BindingContext;

    await viewModel.ProcessPayment();
}
```

This is part of the PaymentPageViewModel:

```
private readonly IStripeRepository _repository;
private readonly IAPIRepository _api;

public PaymentPageViewModel(IStripeRepository repository, IAPIRepository api)
{
    _repository = repository;
    _api = api;
}

public async Task ProcessPayment()
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExpirationDate))
            ExpirationDate = "09/18";

        var exp = ExpirationDate.Split('/');
        var token = _repository.CreateToken(CreditCardNumber, exp[0], exp[1], SecurityCode);
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Test Message", token, "OK");
        await _api.ChargeCard(token, 5.00M);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
    }
}
```

This is what the APIRepository looks like:

```
public class APIRepository: IAPIRepository
{
    const string Url = "http://localhost:5000";
    private string authorizationKey;

    private async Task<HttpClient> GetClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationKey))
        {
            authorizationKey = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            authorizationKey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(authorizationKey);
        }

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authorizationKey);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        return client;
    }



    public async Task<string> ChargeCard(string token, decimal amount)
    {
        HttpClient client = await GetClient();

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { token, amount });

        var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Stripe", new StringContent(json));

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

The issue is that I get a series of errors during await _api.ChargeCard(token, 5.00M):

The first exception happens during authorizationKey = await client.GetStringAsync(Url); the exception message is the following:

{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 404 (Not Found)   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode () [0x0000a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.2.0.11/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpResponseM…}

I get another exception during response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Stripe", new StringContent(json));

{System.InvalidOperationException: The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Thr…}

The third exception happens at the catch block of the viewModel.ProcessPayment() method:

{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object   at Zwaby.Services.APIRepository+d__3.MoveNext () [0x00184] in /Users/carlos/Projects/Zwaby/Zwaby/Services/APIRepository.cs:57  --- End of stack trace from previou…}

In my Web API project, I have a StripeController, but my implementation may not be fully correct:

```
[Route("api/Stripe")]
public class StripeController : Controller
{
    private readonly StripeContext _context;

    public StripeController(StripeContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        if (_context.StripeCharges.Count() == 0)
        {
            _context.StripeCharges.Add(new StripeItem { });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get(string key)
    {
        // TODO: implement method that returns authorization key
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Charge(string stripeToken, decimal amount)
    {
        var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
        var charges = new StripeChargeService();

        var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions
        {
            SourceToken = stripeToken
        });

        var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = (int)amount,
            Description = "Sample Charge",
            Currency = "usd",
            CustomerId = customer.Id
        });

        return View();
    }

}
```

For completeness, I am including the StripeRepository class, the other parameter of the PaymentPageViewModel:

```
public class StripeRepository: IStripeRepository
{
    public string CreateToken(string cardNumber, string cardExpMonth, string cardExpYear, string cardCVC)
    {
        StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey("my_test_key");

        //TODO: Wireup card information below

        var tokenOptions = new StripeTokenCreateOptions()
        {
            Card = new StripeCreditCardOptions()
            {
                Number = "4242424242424242",
                ExpirationYear = 2018,
                ExpirationMonth = 10,
                Cvc = "123"
            }
        };

        var tokenService = new StripeTokenService();

        StripeToken stripeToken = tokenService.Create(tokenOptions);

        return stripeToken.Id;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: "I get an error" - please tell us specifically what the error is.

Comment: Well, the Error DisplayAlert pops up: catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
    } .  This happens during authorizationKey = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);

Comment: You need to learn how to use the debugging tools.

Comment: I think the client (Xamarin.Forms app) is failing to establish a connection with the local web API.

Comment: Knowing the value of the exception would tell you that.  And as has been pointed out hundreds of times on SO, you should not use "localhost" when testing webservices with mobile.

Comment: {System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b0] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Version…}

Comment: are you still using localhost?

Comment: Yes. I know you said not to, but I was told that it would work. If it CANNOT work with localhost, I should host it in Azure and use a 'real' url?

Comment: use the actual IP of the machine hosting the service?

Comment: Thanks Jason. So just replace const string Url = "http://localhost:5000"; with const string Url = "my_IP"?

Comment: no, just replace "localhost" with the correct IP

Comment: After changing it to const string Url = "http://my_IP_Value:5000"; I get this exception: 
 {System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.   at System.Uri.CreateThis (System.String uri, System.Boolean dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) [0x0007b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/refere…} same thing if I remove the port number

Comment: That's when using the long IP (IPv6). When I use the shorter one (IPv4), I get this exception: {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (Syste…}

Comment: The above discussion has been resolved. The issue was that the local web API had to be actively running already when called from Xamarin.Forms. The problem flow has been updated.